# What is the right way to ask this question?

Tags: discussion, support

I asked: [How to concentrate magnetic fields using the least amount of material possible for a fixed area](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/53466/how-to-concentrate-magnetic-fields-using-the-least-amount-of-material-possible-f)

But I think its a low quality question. For a few reasons:

1. perhaps my drawings aren't that great but even if they were good,
2. perhaps my rules are not very well defined, I have access to a magnetic material, a diamagnetic material (And you can add an X material as needed) but even if they were
3. perhaps my interpretation of how the physics works/how the field lines would bend is wrong
4. even if all those things are correct the question is somehow still ugly looking.

I'm having trouble articulating exactly what I want to ask. What I know is im trying to look for contraptions that redirect field lines (assumed to be below the object and pointing straight up INTO a particular point).

I think if I see how an experienced engineer would ask the same question I would have a better mental model of what I need to do. I only have vague ideas of good practices for questions from other stackexchange sites.

Comment: The original question sounds like an XY problem. What is the final application ? Is it to have a concentrated magnetic field in some region or is the goal to reduce the field intensity in some region by "*pushing all the field away*" to some other region ? Where does the minimise-material-constraint come from ?

Comment: For shielding, [see this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mu-metal)

Comment: So your gonna laugh at this but here goes. I am working on a toy problem where I pin a superconductor to a planetary magnetic field but since the field has low strength we want to take the flux of a wide area of field and concentrate it into much smaller region.

Comment: So the idea was to create some structure for harvesting and concentrating these field lines and hang it from the type2 superconductor to have it collect magnetic field lines and try to bring them towards the superconductor. I wasn't sure if this was a relevant detail to include though

Comment: I don't know much about this, but I think that you will end up pinning the superconductor *not* to planet, but to this *concentrator* instead.